# Can't use select and eventClick together in fullcalendar using react

Tags: reactjs, select, events, fullcalendar

Select call back works fine till i put eventClick callback.. then select crashes, i need to use both of them so i can add events by select and remove events by eventClick

```js
<FullCalendar
  ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  plugins={[BootstrapTheme, dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  slotDuration={"00:15:00"}
  minTime={"08:00:00"}
  maxTime={"19:00:00"}
  handleWindowResize={true}
  themeSystem="bootstrap"
  header={{
    left: "prev,next today",
    center: "title",
    right: "dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay",
  }}
  select={this.modal}
  editable={true}
  eventReceive={this.handleDrop}
  droppable={true}
  eventClick={() => console.log("event clicked")}
  selectable={true}
  events={this.state.calendarEvents}
  id="calendar"
/>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error do you see when it crashes?

Comment: I added images for the error.. please check

Comment: Ok. So this happens when you try to load the calendar? Or only when you try to click on an event? Or something else?

Comment: P.s. which version of fullCalendar are you using?

Comment: It happens exactly when i try to set a state using select callback.. but when i remove setState from the function it works fine. and i use version: 3.10.2

Comment: You can't be using version 3.10 - it doesn't have plugins, and it doesn't have an Angular component ready-made. It looks more like you are using version 4, or maybe 5. (P.S. If you _are_ using version 3 in some/all of your code, that could be a reason for your problem!)

Comment: I got version number from package.json file.. should i update it?

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert. But yes you should make sure you are using v4 or above of fullCalendar. It has a ready-made Angular component, it's described in the documentation on the fullCalendar website